# Migration in Laravel 8, does not let me put foreign key in the default table of users

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-8

I have an error when placing a foreign key in the users table of laravel.

I have the Laravel users table, and I want to relate it to the employees table, which will have the personal data of the employees, but when I try to put the foreign key inside the users table, I get an error:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table name_data_base.users (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

This error only occurs in this relationship, since I have more tables and it does not give me a problem.

This is the code for the two tables:

**employees table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('person_id')->references('id')->on('people');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**users table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
    });
}
```

Comment: The order that the tables are created is important.  You cannot create a foreign key constraint to a table that does not yet exist.  Order the migrations by their filename so you know which order they run in.  Sometimes it is best to create a migration just for the FKs after the tables are created

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined column `employee_id` in employees table migration file Schema:
Remember `employee_id` column type, length or unsigned like properties should be same users table primary key `id`. Here is docs help:[Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('person_id')->references('id')->on('people');
    //By default laravel create primary key with bigInteger in latest versions
    $table->bigInteger('employee_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

   $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Now run `php artisan migrate` so it will create table `employees` and foreign key too.